# Install a pfx certificate on a remote server with powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, installation, pfx

By following this, 
[Install certificate with PowerShell on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278492/install-certificate-with-powershell-on-remote-server)

I'm trying to install a pfx certificate on a remote server by using the following Powershell command,

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName myservername -scriptblock { Import-PfxCertificate –FilePath D:\pfxcert.pfx cert:\localMachine\my -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -Force –AsPlainText) }
```

This is giving below error message for me...

```
The term 'Import-PfxCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Import-PfxCertificate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
+ PSComputerName        : myservername
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 2):

The Cmdlet `Import-PfxCertificate` is part of the module `PKIClient`.

The PKI Client Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell are only available on

- Windows 8.1
- Windows PowerShell 4.0
- Windows Server 2012 R2

Try to load the PKI Client in your Script:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName myservername -scriptblock 
{ 
    Get-Command -Module PKIClient; 
    Import-PfxCertificate –FilePath D:\pfxcert.pfx cert:\localMachine\my -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -Force –AsPlainText) 
}
```

You could try `Get-Command -Module PKIClient` to see  all cmdlets.

Comment: It seems that it should be at least Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2 (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848625(v=wps.630).aspx), i.e. a more current version of PowerShell such as 4.0 or 5.0 alone does not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The `Import-PfxCertificate` cmdlet does not exist on the target machine. Probably because it is running a version of Powershell less than 3.

You'll have to install a newer version of PowerShell if possible, or find a different method of importing the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Could you please share some example of how to achieve this in other way? I have to call this powershell script in c# code.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't really work like that. You'll need to research alternative methods yourself. If you get stuck, come back and post another question saying where. The site is not a code writing service, its very unlikely anyone will write the entire script for you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to call it from C# anyway, then it will be probably worth to install it from C#, like

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\TEMP\yourcerthere.pfx", "yourpasswordhere");
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

It will be approx the same code in powershell actually, since it's no other way but use .net system class or some tool like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384088(VS.85)).