# How can I renew my SSL certificate on aws normal ec2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl

Godaddy SSL certificate is already installed on my server. But now I want to change it to namecheap but I don't know where to put my new certificate files as last time it was installed by another developer. can somebody please help?

Comment: are you running Nginx or apache ?

Comment: What is the web container you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open the **Amazon EC2 console** at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. On the navigation pane, under **LOAD BALANCING**, choose **Load Balancers**.
3. Select your **load balancer**.
4. On the **Listeners tab**, for **SSL Certificate**, choose **Change**.
5. On the **Select Certificate** page, do one of the following:

   - If you created or imported a certificate using AWS Certificate Manager, select **Choose an existing certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM)**, select the certificate from **Certificate**, and then choose **Save**.
   - If you imported a certificate using IAM, select **Choose an existing certificate from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)**, select the certificate from **Certificate**, and then choose **Save**.
   - If you have a certificate to import but ACM is not supported in the region, select **Upload a new SSL Certificate to AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)**. Type a name for the certificate, copy the required information to the form, and then choose **Save**. Note that the certificate chain is not required if the certificate is a self-signed certificate.

If you want further details you can study the relevant AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-update-ssl-cert.html)

Comment: There is no load balancer on this instance brother neither any other service like cloudfront or  api gateway.

Comment: If you are not using load balancer I think your answer can find here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022890/how-to-update-ssl-certificate-on-ec2-instances